# Animation In Windows Phone 7 (WP7) Simpliest Method?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, animation

**Background:**

I'd really love to add some animation to my small text-based game demo I've been making, the main code for the game itself is almost there or roundabouts.

I'm happy with my progress so far -- but I'd love to breathe some life into it, and make it much better than it currently is through animations.

**The Issue:**

The methods I've found prior to asking for assistance have all involved "Silverlight" or a "Storyboard"

As a novice programmer and as someone generally new to c# I have no idea what any of this means or have seen it work in any real context as of yet. Tutorials are also really vague and the programmers don't explain their code or what it does.

**What I'd like to do:**

I'd like for when the user presses a button a small animation would begin to play, and in some places a seperate animation could be constantly on such as a banner animation.

**Example:**

When I push a button:

- I'd like an animation to appear that looks similar to a Gif of a small flame which would appear on screen as an animated image.
- Since there is only really going to be three/four locations per page maximum, I can just use three seperate imageboxes.

I'd like it to work within the existing "Image" constructs avaliable to be placed within Visual studios WYSIWYG drap and drop system.

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve, something similar to the flames above the braizers to the left and right of the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKmW9gNENJA

**What I'm using:**

I'm using XAML, I'm not using XNA at all. I'm just using WP7 as default which comes with cs and XAML.

**EXTRA Example of particle effects:**

Although this isn't related, the "Particle effects" found in the video below are also something I wanted to achieve eventually.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w3dJIGSzPo&list=PLE4TZmqEfiRIy-4vyGwfNhOAuI8YwXF7T&index=48

---

- So, basically, in plain english -- what is the eaisest, and best way to make an animation for use in a WP7 application.
- And, how would one start the process of making an animation like this?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Storyboard is indeed the correct way to animate in WPF/Silverlight. However, you are either using XNA or WP7 XAML (like WPF, but not quite the same). Which one are you using? You've provided some good information, but a little bit of code and knowing what technology you are using would be great.

Comment: Hey Bradley. I'm using XAML. The XNA was the game related stuff which I wanted to actually avoid purposefully.

Comment: Ok, particle effects won't be easy, but I'm happy to help with the storyboards. Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard(v=vs.110).aspx for the documentation? Could you narrow the question a bit? I'll try and put together a basic storyboard explanation as an answer, but any narrowing would be very helpful.

Comment: I have, but I'm still having issues.

Comment: I'd learn way more from a visual example of something actually working. I'm not a very experienced coder.

Comment: I posted an answer that covers the basics of storyboards, leave any questions in the comments and I'll get to them sometime tonight or at the latest tomorrow. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm going to read over what you said and try to put it to good use and I'll come back later once I understand what's happening.

Thanks so much though In the meantine, really apperciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty broad, so I'll tackle it in pieces:

1. A "particle" effect will be a very complex storyboard. The video you linked to is clearly using XNA for some pieces of the application, and that is likely where the particles live, since it is simpler using that technology.
2. There isn't any real reason to use the image control here. Microsoft doesn't support the GIF format, so any animation you want will have to be done by hand anyways. If you just wanted to animate a static "flame" image, an image control would work. That's the only case I can think of to use one.
3. Now for the meat, here is a sample storyboard:

   ```
   <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Flame" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FlameTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
         <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-100"/>
         <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
         <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames> 
   </Storyboard>
   ```

Assuming there is a control declared like:

```
<Image x:Name="Flame">
   <Image.RenderTransform x:Name="FlameTranslateTransform">
      <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
   </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

To explain, you have to start with a Storyboard element. This element then contains animations. The animations use `Storyboard.TargetName` to set the name of the element they will act on, and `Storyboard.TargetProperty` to set the name of the property to modify.

I gave both an example of a standard animation (using `From` and `To` which just does a linear interpolation between the two over the specified `Duration`) and a keyframe animation (which goes between each key frame in the specified time, I used linear interpolation again).

I also set `RepeatBehavior` to `Forever` so it will continuously loop. This animation will move the flame image from side to side, and fade it in and out. You could name the storyboard and start it in code-behind, or use a trigger: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744905(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744905%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Please let me know if I can clarify anything, hopefully the above helps!

Comment: Would that storyboard work in XAML? Sorry I'm just lost here.

Going to update the main comment.

Comment: The provided code *is* XAML :). So I think the answer to your question is yes. Is there a specific piece that confuses you?

Comment: I'm unsure how the XAML actually works, my XAML doesn't seem to work with the code you provided.

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work"? Your storyboard needs to be in a trigger or resource. I haven't seen any of your code, and my code was just an attempt to explain storyboards. I'm not sure how to help without more information

Comment: I mean, I just really wanted to understand how to incorporate animation into C#

I'm very new to everything, Storyboards, XAML, even the enviroment itself.

It'd be great if someone could just explain the process to me in plain english.

I'vew grateful for your code, but I really can't understand how to set a system such as a storyboard up without fully understanding what it does, where it gets it's information from etc.

Comment: I'm glad you want to learn, it seems to be a rare trait nowadays (just look at half the meta conversations). I'll be back on in about an hour, perhaps we could chat and I could try to get you started?

Comment: Please join me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51763/conversation-regarding-animation-in-wpf and I will be happy to answer any questions you may have!